# Apex: how to reduce soql commands by using left outer join (sub query)?

Tags: salesforce, left-join, apex-code, apex

Below is my Schedulable apex code. I would like to select data from 5 tables: wkCSRCorderMaster__c(main), InstallationMaster__c, AddressMaster__c, ItemMaster__c, and ItemAddonMaster__c.

Basically, there are some relationships among them but I don't know how to use sub-query or write as 'left outer join' in this case. Hence, I divided them by some of distinct queries as you can see.

The problem is that there's a lot of data in wkCSRCorderMaster once time (about 50-100 records), but Apex Execution Governors Limitation for SOQL commands is just only 100 times for Synchronous Limit and 200 times Asynchronous Limit.

Therefore, my code will not work as I expected.

Please help me to consider whether I can reduce SOQL commands or combine them into just only 1 by using Left Outer Join syntax or sub query.

```
Global class C_Apex_CSRCUpdate implements Schedulable {

 Global void execute (SchedulableContext SC){

 // Constant variable

    String ListElement;     // List Element 
    String tempCompany;     // Company
    String tempRecordType;  // Record Type          

 // Constant for Incident Record

    String IncCategory = [SELECT Id FROM BMCServiceDesk__Category__c WHERE Name = :'ServiceRequest.'].Id;   // Incident Category
    String IncImpact   = [SELECT Id FROM BMCServiceDesk__Impact__c   WHERE Name = :'low.'].Id;              // Incident Impact 
    String IncUrgency  = [SELECT Id FROM BMCServiceDesk__Urgency__c  WHERE Name = :'low.'].Id;              // Incident Urgency 
    String IncStatus   = [SELECT Id FROM BMCServiceDesk__Status__c   WHERE Name = :'Close.'].Id;            // Incident Status 

 // List Incident
    List<BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c> wkIncList = new List<BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c>();    

 // Assignment    
     for(wkCSRCorderMaster__c wkCSRCorderMaster: [SELECT  Id,                                                   // wkCSRCorderMaster ID
                                                          Name,                                                 // wkCSRCorderMaster Name 
                                                          CreatedDate,                                          // wkCSRCorderMaster CreatedDate
                                                          HAIS_SK_NAME__c,                                      // wkCSRCorderMaster HAIS_SK_NAME
                                                          HAIS_SK_ADD1__c,                                      // wkCSRCorderMaster HAIS_SK_ADD1 
                                                          HAIS_SK_ADD2__c,                                      // wkCSRCorderMaster HAIS_SK_ADD2  
                                                          HAIS_SK_ADD3__c,                                      // wkCSRCorderMaster HAIS_SK_ADD3
                                                          HAIS_SK_TEL__c,                                       // wkCSRCorderMaster HAIS_SK_TEL
                                                          JTCH_DMPY_NO__c,                                      // wkCSRCorderMaster JTCH_DMPY_NO
                                                          HMMK_CD__c,                                           // wkCSRCorderMaster HMMK_CD
                                                          NEW_ITEM_CD__c,                                       // wkCSRCorderMaster NEW_ITEM_CD
                                                          OYA_KBN__c,                                           // wkCSRCorderMaster OYA_KBN
                                                          STCI_DATE__c                                          // wkCSRCorderMaster STCI_DATE

                                                    FROM  wkCSRCorderMaster__c ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC]){   

 // Select data from wkInstallationMaster based on wkCSRCorderMaster
    InstallationMaster__c InstallationMaster =  [SELECT Id,
                                                            Name,
                                                            MACHINE_ID__c,
                                                            KBN__c
                                                       FROM InstallationMaster__c
                                                      WHERE HMMK_CD__c   =: wkCSRCorderMaster.NEW_ITEM_CD__c
                                                        AND KBN__c       =: wkCSRCorderMaster.OYA_KBN__c
                                                        AND STCI_DATE__c =: wkCSRCorderMaster.STCI_DATE__c
                                                        AND EIGY_TNTO_BMN_CD__c IN ('M76' , 'N99')];   

 // Select data from AddressMaster based on wkCSRCorderMaster     
    AddressMaster__c wkAddressMaster = [SELECT Id,
                                               Name,
                                               JUSHO_KNJ__c
                                          FROM AddressMaster__c
                                         WHERE JUSHO_CD__c =: wkCSRCorderMaster.HAIS_SK_ADD1__c]; 

 // Select data from ItemMaster based on wkCSRCorderMaster 
    ItemMaster__c wkItemMaster = [SELECT Id,
                                         Name,
                                         MAKTX2__c
                                    FROM ItemMaster__c
                                   WHERE Name =: wkCSRCorderMaster.HMMK_CD__c];

 // Select data from ItemAddonMaster based on wkCSRCorderMaster
    ItemAddonMaster__c wkItemAddonMaster = [SELECT Id, 
                                                   Name,
                                                   KSHU_NAME__c
                                              FROM ItemAddonMaster__c
                                             WHERE HMMK_CD__c =: wkCSRCorderMaster.HMMK_CD__c];          

 // Get Company name from MachineID
    tempRecordType = GetRecordType(InstallationMaster.MACHINE_ID__c);

         // New Incident            
            BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c wkInc   =  new BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c();

            wkInc.Gender__c                     = 'unknown';                                                // Gender
            wkInc.BMCServiceDesk__FKCategory__c =  IncCategory;                                             // Category
            wkInc.Product_category__c           = 'MFP-KM';                                                 // Product category
            wkInc.Resolution_result__c          = 'エスカレーション';                                         // Resolution result                           
            wkInc.BMCServiceDesk__FKImpact__c   =  IncImpact;                                               // Impact                              
            wkInc.BMCServiceDesk__FKUrgency__c  =  IncUrgency;                                              // Urgency                           
            wkInc.BMCServiceDesk__FKStatus__c   =  IncStatus;                                               // Status 
            wkInc.RecordTypeId                  =  tempRecordType;                                          // RecordType
            wkInc.Change_InstallationCustomerName__c   =  wkCSRCorderMaster.HAIS_SK_NAME__c;                // Installation phone 
            wkInc.Change_InstallationAddress__c =  wkAddressMaster.JUSHO_KNJ__c + ' ' + wkCSRCorderMaster.HAIS_SK_ADD2__c + ' ' + wkCSRCorderMaster.HAIS_SK_ADD2__c; 
            wkInc.MID__c                        =  InstallationMaster.MACHINE_ID__c;                        // MachineID
            wkInc.Change_InstallationPhone__c   =  wkCSRCorderMaster.HAIS_SK_TEL__c;                        // Installation phone

            wkInc.Subject__c                    = 'iCare発送済み：'+ wkItemMaster.MAKTX2__c;                 // Incident subject

         // Add wkInc to List
            wkIncList.add(wkInc);   

            System.debug('▼ [CSRCUpdate] add incident to list.');

         // delete wkCSRCorderMaster;

       } // End for        


        try{
            insert wkIncList;
            System.debug('▼ [CSRCUpdate] insert completed.');

           }catch(system.DmlException e){
            System.debug('Cannot insert new Incident because following exception has occurred:' + e.getMessage() + e.getStackTraceString());
           } 


    } // End constructor

      // Method to get company name
    public static string GetRecordType(String MachineID){
       String wkRecordType; 
       //String wkCompany;
       String MachineName; 
    try{
       // Get MachineName from MachineID
       List<BMCServiceDesk__BMC_BaseElement__c> tempListMachineName = [SELECT Name 
                                                                         FROM BMCServiceDesk__BMC_BaseElement__c
                                                                        WHERE Id =: MachineID];

        if(tempListMachineName.size()>0){
           MachineName =        [SELECT Name 
                                   FROM BMCServiceDesk__BMC_BaseElement__c
                                  WHERE Id =: MachineID Limit 1].Name; 
        } else{
          System.debug('There is no MachineName related to MachineID');  
        }

        if(MachineName.startsWith('NU')){
            //wkCompany = 'UNISYS';
            wkRecordType = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE Name = :'BJ-INC-UNISYS'].Id;
        }else{
            //wkCompany = 'ANA';
            wkRecordType = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE Name = :'BJ-INC-ANA'].Id;
        }        

         // Return incident RecordType     
            return wkRecordType;

        }catch(System.DmlException e){
            return e.getMessage();
        }      

    }// End method

} // End class
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search will give you many examples of good SOQL queries, such as 
http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/02/22/soql-how-i-query-with-thee-let-me-count-the-ways/.

Comment: Thank EricSSH for your promt answer. I will try it.

Answer (score -1):

Even if it's not standard SQL, you can outer join if your objects are correctly related in salesforce:

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com